# I can't configure crypto watch API in ZigZag market maker

Tags: javascript, api

I don't understand what to do with the cryptowatch configuration. Tell me what am I doing wrong,
how to set up pairs

Link to github, it explains what needs to be done, scroll down to the cryptowatch section
https://github.com/ZigZagExchange/market-maker

Comment: "pairs": {
        "ETH-USDC": {
            "priceFeedPrimary": "cryptowatch:6631",
            "priceFeedSecondary": "cryptowatch:588",
            "slippageRate": 1e-5,
            "maxSize": 100,
            "minSize": 0.0003,
            "minSpread": 0.0005,
            "active": true
        },

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.